# If I have two things that activate at the beginning of the end step, what happens?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What happens if I have two cards that have an effect that happens at the beginning of my end step? Which of them activates first, or do they activate at the same time.

I am asking because I am using:

[image][image]

Both of them have an effect that activates at the begining of the end step, but could I exile Obzedat before the Revolt effect activates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't get the servo.

Hidden Stockpile has an "intervening if" trigger, which means it checks the state to see if it even goes on the stack.  If a creature had not left before the end step, then it won't ever go on the stack.

> 603.4. A triggered ability may read “When/Whenever/At [trigger event], if [condition], [effect].” When the trigger event occurs, the ability checks whether the stated condition is true. The ability triggers only if it is; otherwise it does nothing. If the ability triggers, it checks the stated condition again as it resolves. If the condition isn’t true at that time, the ability is removed from the stack and does nothing. Note that this mirrors the check for legal targets. This rule is referred to as the “intervening ‘if’ clause” rule. (The word “if” has only its normal English meaning anywhere else in the text of a card; this rule only applies to an “if” that immediately follows a trigger condition.)

Answer (score 6):

None of these abilities "activate", they trigger. In particular, [Hidden Stockpile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHidden%20Stockpile%5d) only triggers if a permanent you controlled left the battlefield this turn. [Obzedat, Ghost Council](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bObzedat%2c%20Ghost%20Council%5d) exiling itself in the end step won't happen in time to meet this condition. This is due to what's called an intervening if clause. If no permanent you controlled left the battlefield this turn, only Obzedat will trigger.

> **603.4.** A triggered ability may read “When/Whenever/At [trigger event], if [condition], [effect].” When the trigger event occurs, the ability checks whether the stated condition is true. The ability triggers only if it is; otherwise it does nothing. (...)

Assuming another permanent did leave the battlefield, both abilities trigger at the same time - at the beginning of the end step. Since you control both abilities, you choose the order in which they are put on the stack.

> **603.3b.** If multiple abilities have triggered since the last time a player received priority, each player (...) puts triggered abilities he or she controls on the stack in any order he or she chooses. (...)

Comment: Okay, I see. They would both trigger at the exact same time, so Revolt would not get activated.